# Maintaining state with a local static site

Tags: javascript, html, url, state

I have a static HTML site that is going to run off CD. It's going to have two different viewing modes, which I'm going to switch between with JavaScript. I'd like to maintain the viewing mode during the session. It's a JavaScript-powered document reader thing.

I'm using the query string and a hash to dynamically link to certain things - I've got JavaScript that's ready the query string and hash. My URLs generally look something like this:

```
index.html?ch2#fig01
```

where `?ch2` loads chapter 2 and `#fig01` jumps to figure 1 in that chapter.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use multiple parameters in the URL, ex: index.html?Chapter=2&Figure=1&View=Full

Comment: @Zachary - mainly laziness and time pressure. I've not got long to finish this and changing the URL structure at this stage would mean some major rewriting. It was a last-minute change from the client, otherwise I would have tried to do something about it sooner :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cookie.

```
document.cookie = "option=value";
```

Reading it's a little more complicated:

```
var c = document.cookie.split(";");
while(c[0] && c[0].indexOf("option") == -1) c.shift();
if( c[0]) {
   var value = c[0].split("=")[1];
}
else {
    // cookie not found, default
}
```

Comment: Yes I can. Thank you! (I'd completely forgotten about the existence of cookies :P)